# :: acting as delimiter in my csv file and spliting data

Tags: python, django

I have a django template where I have stored some tables and have written a function to export it to csv but when i am doing it some columns in my table have :: in them and csv is treating it as a delimiter and splitting the column there how can i prevent this from happening

my views.py

```
f = open("static/output.csv", "w")

f.write("Customer Name" + "," + "Status" + "," + "Product" + "," + "Operating System" + "," +"Server_Type" + "," + "Version"+"," +"Citrux_URL"+"," +"F5_URL"+","+"\n")

for c in custom:
    f.write(c.summarise()+"\n")
```

my models.py

```
def summarise(self):
    s = ",".join([str(self.name), str(self.Status), str(self.Product),str(self.SSO),str(self.SSO_URL),str(self.JCES_URL),str(self.L3),str(self.PM))])
    return s
```

Comment: how do I modify summarise so that :: is not treated as a delimiter

Comment: You are not using the `csv writer`

Comment: And give an example where you are using `:` as well

Answer (score 0):

Use the csv writer to correctly handle `special characters` as `delimiters`. It is defined by the `quoting` argument of the `csv_writer`. In your case you can skip this attribute completely, as it will default to `QUOTE_MINIMAL` when not defined. Still added into the example for completeness.

**Source:**

```
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(["te,st:foo", "test:nope, yes", "nodelimiter"])
```

**output.csv:**

```
"te,st:foo","test:nope, yes",nodelimiter
```

CSV is automatically controlling when quotes should be generated by the writer and recognised by the reader. It can take on any of the `QUOTE_*` constants  and defaults to `quote_minimal`

> **QUOTE_MINIMAL** Instructs writer objects to only quote those fields which contain special characters such as delimiter, quotechar or any of the characters in lineterminator.
>
> **NOTE** You are passing a string, you need to pass a list of strings

```
def summarise(self):
    s = [str(self.name), str(self.Status), str(self.Product),str(self.SSO),str(self.SSO_URL),str(self.JCES_URL),str(self.L3),str(self.PM))]
    return s
```

Comment: still "Prod: aeon-cpfr.jdadelivers.com , Test: aeon-cpfr-test.jdadelivers.com, Dev: aeon-cpfr-test.jdadelivers.com" is splitted into new columns

Comment: Try `csv.QUOTE_ALL` instead of `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` your test-case works for me even with `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`. Are you checking the output of the csv writer in a text editor?

Comment: nope not working for me I have added it like this writer.writerow(c.summarise()+"\n") but still while fetching data from the columns it is treating comma's inside text as delimiter's    also I was filtering data earlier but now it is sending all the data in the excel stored in my models

Comment: From your source, are you doing `writer.writerow(s)` ? If yes that won't work as you are already giving it a full string. If you would share what your data looks like and a reproducible line how you use `writer.writerow` i could probably help.

Comment: import csv
    with open('output.csv','w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for c in custom:
            writer.writerow(c.summarise()+"\n")

Comment: how should I modify it?

Comment: Ok, look at the summarise function i'v added, don't pass a string but a list of strings. That should work. And you don't need the '\n'. csv writer takes care of that.

Comment: I dont know why but now it is exporting the same output every time

Comment: How are you getting your data in first place? Are you reading it from text file?

Comment: i am taking it from django model i have saved the summarise functions in my model.py and my js file is function exp(){
    
    window.open("/static/output.csv","_self");
}

Comment: Sorry but remote debugging is getting complicated, i don't think i can help you from here on, but poking around you should find my thread useful. Good Luck.